# Displaying header in first page only on crystal reports c#

Tags: c#, crystal-reports

I have a crystal report to print an invoice. I have a page header with details like Item number, quantity etc. I want it to display in first page only. Currently if more items than a page comes rest of the items will be printed in 2nd page. I don't want the page header to display on all pages. I want it to display on first page only. Means i want it to display one time only. I have solved a similar problem with report footer. i wanted it at last page only. So i suppressed the fields and written the formula

PageNumber <> TotalPageCount

so how to display page header in first page only? and how to display a box object in last page only. Can someone help me with that?

Answer (score 1):

Place that details inside the Report Header, hence it will displayed in the first page only. Or use the suppress formula to hide the details for the other pages.

Please look into this [link](https://www.kb.blackbaud.com/articles/Article/38218).

Comment: Thanks for responding. I have used the formula PageNumber <> 1. Can u say how to show box object in last page only.

Comment: You can place into report footer.

Answer (score 0):

1. Just go to the report heading right click on it.
2. Section Expert then Suppress( no drill down)
3. Write it `PageNumber > 1`
4. Save